# Amazon SageMaker soft max label must be in [0, num_class)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, softmax

I am starting on a multiclass classification problem using Xgboost and experimenting with SageMaker HyperparameterTuner. It looks like everything is configured correctly, but I keep getting failed statuses. When I check the CloudWatch logs I can see this is the problem. "SoftmaxMultiClassObj: label must be in [0, num_class)." I know how many classes I have in the data 5 (0,1,2,3,4) and they are in the first column of of both the training and validation data sets.

Below are my configurations:

```
xgb = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(container,
                                        role, 
                                        train_instance_count=1, 
                                        train_instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                                        output_path='s3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix),
                                        sagemaker_session=sess)

xgb.set_hyperparameters(eval_metric='merror', #'rmse',
                            objective = 'multi:softmax',#'binary:logistic',
                            num_round=100,
                            rate_drop=0.3,
                            num_class= 5)

hyperparameter_ranges = {'eta': ContinuousParameter(0, 1),
                        'min_child_weight': ContinuousParameter(1, 10),
                        'alpha': ContinuousParameter(0, 2),
                        'max_depth': IntegerParameter(1, 10)}

objective_metric_name = 'validation:accuracy'

tuner = HyperparameterTuner(xgb,
                            objective_metric_name,
                            hyperparameter_ranges,
                            max_jobs=20,
                            max_parallel_jobs=3)

s3_input_train = sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/TrainingData'.format(bucket, prefix), content_type='csv')
s3_input_validation = sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/ValidationData'.format(bucket, prefix), content_type='csv')

tuner.fit({'train': s3_input_train, 'validation': s3_input_validation}, include_cls_metadata=False)
```

And for good measures here is the set for the first column of the dataset to show there is indeed 5 classes.

```
data=pd.read_csv('TrainingData.csv')
set(data['0'])

{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

I have restarted the SageMaker training jobs multiple times and the notebook itself but continue to get the same error. What are your thoughts to try?

Comment: I think the error is quite clear (but might be confusing indeed). Could you try changing `num_class` to `4` instead of `5`? From the error should be exclusive (`5)`) while yours is inclusive.

Comment: I wish it was something that simple. I tried your suggestion and got the same exact error. SoftmaxMultiClassObj: label must be in [0, num_class). I am guessing it has something to do with how this line reads int eh data. s3_input_train = sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/TrainingData.csv'.format(bucket, prefix), content_type='csv')

Comment: I can't see anything pointing algorithm to the labels. Are you sure it points to them correctly? Maybe it uses another column as target? Or are those always assumed to be first column? Is `.csv` correct format (maybe those need `np.array` types?)

Comment: With Xgboost the first column is always the label, so that should be fine.  I think it is most likely a format issue but the error is not helping much. There seams to be a few posts online about the Hyper parameter tuning on SageMaker has some issues with defaulting values. There is not a posted solutions though to the problem.

Comment: Not sure if you saved your data with `pd.read_csv` (I assume so), but you probably have to specify `index=False` so there is no additional column created with row indices. `set(data[`0`])` __does not necessarily__ correspond to the first column. `data[data.columns[0]]` will though, is the output the same?

Comment: Yes the out put of those two are the same. I actually never load the data to a pd dataframe. I just have that as an example of what the data looks like. Sagemaker expects to be reading from an S3 input which is what the s3_input does. I really does feel like there is something wrong there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210952/discussion-between-szymon-maszke-and-droid).

Comment: So, do we have a solution to this issue?